# multiple JOIN in SQL

Tags: mysql, join

Here is my Table Desgin

```
PERSON
DriverID (primary)
DriverName
Address

CAR
RegNO (primary) 
Model 
Year

ACCIDENT
ReportNumber (primary)
AccidentDate
Location

OWNS
DriverID (primary key)  foreign key with PERSON(DriverID)
RegNo (primary Key) foreign key with CAR(RegNo)

PARTICIPATION
DriverID (primary key) foreign key with PERSON (DriverID)
RegNo (primary Key) foreign key with CAR(RegNo)
ReportNumber (primary key) foregin with ACCIDENT(primary)
Damage Amount
```

Now i want to join all of these tables
so the following column should be output
DriverID 
DriverName
Address
RegNo
Model
Year
ReportNumber
AccidentDate
Location
DamageAMount

Answer (score 1):

Try this ::

```
Select
* 
from 
participation pt

inner join PERSON p on (p.DriverID = pt.DriverID )
inner join car c on (pt.RegNo =c.RegNo)
inner join accidents a on (pt.ReportNumber =a.ReportNumber)
```

The delete query is

```
delete
from 
participation pt

inner join PERSON p on (p.DriverID = pt.DriverID )
inner join car c on (pt.RegNo =c.RegNo)
inner join accidents a on (pt.ReportNumber =a.ReportNumber)
where p.DriverID = 111
```

Comment: please someone 
help its urgent
i'm doing a project on this with php

Comment: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'on PERSON p (p.DriverID = pt.DriverID )
inner join car c on (pt.RegNo =c.RegNo)' at line 6

Comment: Try now, If still you are getting any please paste your error message

Comment: thanks very much 
yes now its working
instead of accidents its accident and reportnumber to reportno  but i want PERSON attribute to be displayed first then CAR table attributes then ACCIDENT THEN PARTICIPATION

Comment: You are most welcome, use the select as 
`Select p.*, c.*, a.* from ...`
you will get your desired format

Comment: how to if i want to delete a particular tuple with driverid = 111 and all the related data in various tables should be deleted

Comment: Added the delete query too

Comment: Some error You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'pt

INNER JOIN PERSON p ON (p.DriverID = pt.DriverID )
INNER JOIN car c ON (p' at line 3

Comment: @SashiKant Just an opinion, no offense. You are too nice. Thanks to you more and more people come here and ask for work being done without any research effort, even too lazy to analyze simple syntax errors. This won't really help those guys. If you really want to give an answer, give them a hint what to google, where to look in the manual or whatever. Not the solution right away. In the end it'll be a win-win situation.

Comment: @tombom why u are so jealous

Comment: @dgms I'm not jealous. It's fun to answer questions, but not if more and more people like you come here and want us to do your work for you for free. If you don't want to put any effort in finding a solution, you should hire people working for you. Don't get me wrong, noone here wants money from you. We want interesting questions, and not the same questions all over again and again. And spare yourself those "it's urgent" comments. Do you think we don't have anything else to do? Read this article first, before asking any more questions. http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/

Comment: @tombom: Thanks for your opinion, infact I too agree with you,
dgms: It is not like that, I have to complete your answer, you need to try from your side, and show us where are you facing problem with..
tombom: Thanks once again

Comment: @SashiKant +1 for that, but be aware: The `DELETE` will delete rows from all tables joined!

Comment: @tombom: Thanks and Yes he needed that only...
otherwise I would have done this with a subquery...